# What's the correct way to use sockets in iOS for the different application states?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets

Lets say i have an client application on iOS which is connected to a server using a C socket.
I receive and send data on this socket.

Now the user closes the App, so something else (let's say check his mail) and returns to the application.

My (bundle of) question(s):
What to do with the socket connection?
Should you close it and try to reopen the socket when relaunching the application? 
Or can i leave the socket open? If so, what happens with the data which is received on the connection?

Other situations to consider are:

- I do not know when the user returns to the application.
- I do not know if the user stays in the same network.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection should be closed and the received data saved [if necessary], when the application is about to 'resign active'.

The connection would not be able to run in the background. And you will not receive any data in the background.

When the application resumes from the background reopen the connection and continue.

These methods will help you keep track of your application's state

```
– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

Answer (score 1):

I would close the connection and open a new after the app comes to focus. I wrote an app some months ago where the app talked to a radiostation playoutserver to display some information. 
- you don't know how long the app stays in background
- you don't know if the user stays within the same network
- you don't know if the user forgets about the still in background living app
...

i would vote for closing the socket connection.